# Dagger 2 Scopes and Dependencies in Kotlin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm looking to add Dagger 2 to an existing app and am running into issues with component dependencies and scoping once I get more that 2 levels down. My thought process is to have an `AppComponent`, `LandingActivityComponent` and `LandingFragmentComponent` (not great names right now but we're early) with the scopes `@Singleton`, `@ActivityScope` and `@FragmentScope` respectively. Everything I've done works if I stop at the activity, but once I add the fragment level I get the following error:

```
e: /Users/me/git/myapp-android/myapp/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/regularDebug/tv/myapp/android/app/core/dagger/LandingActivityComponent.java:17: error: com.myapp.android.app.core.LandingActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
    public abstract com.myapp.android.app.core.LandingActivity landingActivity();
                                                               ^
      com.myapp.android.app.core.LandingActivity is provided at
          com.myapp.android.app.core.dagger.LandingActivityComponent.landingActivity()
e: /Users/me/git/myapp-android/myapp/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/regularDebug/tv/myapp/android/app/core/dagger/LandingFragmentComponent.java:13: error: com.myapp.android.app.settings.QuickSettingsPresenter cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
    public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                         ^
      com.myapp.android.app.settings.QuickSettingsPresenter is injected at
          com.myapp.android.app.profile.ProfileViewPagerFragment.mQuickSettingsPresenter
      com.myapp.android.app.profile.ProfileViewPagerFragment is injected at
          com.myapp.android.app.core.dagger.LandingFragmentComponent.inject(profileViewPagerFragment)
```

**Application**

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val app: MyApplication) {

    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideApp(): MyApplication = app

    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = app.applicationContext

    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideAccountManager(): AccountManager = AccountManager(app)
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    // Allow dependents to see the properties provided below
    fun accountManager(): AccountManager
}
```

**Activity**

```
@Scope
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
annotation class ActivityScope

@Module
class LandingActivityModule(private val landingActivity: LandingActivity) {

    @Provides @ActivityScope
    fun provideLandingActivity(): LandingActivity = landingActivity
}

@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = [AppComponent::class], modules = [LandingActivityModule::class])
interface LandingActivityComponent {

    fun inject(landingActivity: LandingActivity)

    // Allow dependents to see the properties provided below
    fun landingActivity(): LandingActivity
    fun accountManager(): AccountManager
}
```

**Fragment**

```
@Scope
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
annotation class FragmentScope

@Module
class LandingFragmentModule(private val landingFragment: LandingFragment) {

    @Provides @FragmentScope
    fun provideFragment(): LandingFragment = landingFragment

    @Provides @FragmentScope
    fun provideQuickSettings(activity: LandingActivity): QuickSettingsPresenter =
            QuickSettingsPresenter.create(activity)
}

@FragmentScope
@Component(dependencies = [LandingActivityComponent::class], modules = [LandingFragmentModule::class])
interface LandingFragmentComponent {

    fun inject(profileViewPagerFragment: ProfileViewPagerFragment)
}
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something fundamental or need to structure things a little differently but I think this highlights what I'm going for.

Interestingly, if I remove the `@Scope` annotations for the `@Provides` in the activity and fragment modules, everything is fine. And as I mentioned, if I cut out the fragment module, I can scope the activity no problem.

The end goal here is to have these components work with presenters as well but I'm kind of going step by step. I'm new to non-monolithic components in Dagger and haven't found a guide or post that's made this click for me.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I figured out what's going on. Somewhere along the way I read something that lead me to believe I needed `@Qualifier` as a part of my scopes but that isn't the case. Removing it seems to have fixed my problem. Will leave this here as a dependency based approach for anyone looking.